# Is X′X/(n − 1) an unbiased estimator of Σ when mean is 0

Tags: statistics, linear-algebra

For example, X is Multivariate normally distributed with mean vector equal to zero. Is X′X/(n − 1) an unbiased estimator of Σ. If the answer is Yes or No, can you explain or prove it mathematically?

Comment: Perhaps asking in Maths StackExchange.

Comment: Yes, you are right